# Theming property non-object when transversing the $node object

Tags: theming, debugging

I'm getting this error when I run the code below, in reference to $color module:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in cotyhouse_preprocess_html()
```

---

```
function cotyhouse_preprocess_html(&$vars){
  // Check if on an article node page
  $node = menu_get_object('node');

  $color = $node->field_title_color;

  print $color;

}
```

When i output it via dpm, it says its an object, so im a bit confused why it would throw an error. The field value does indeed come through.

Answer (score 0):

menu_get_object('node') should be: menu_get_object()

No need for node as its implied when you call that function.

Also you need to put it in a conditional:

if($node = menu_get_object()) {       }